# Removing variables from numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a code which creates [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThqtD.png), but I do not know how to delete first data from "canal 1" - red line, and the last data from "canal 3" - blue line, those vertical lines. There are 266336 records in both canals, can you help?
The red vertical line is a first record, and the blue is the last one.

```
import iodata as io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

testInstance = io.InputConverter()
start = time.time()
conversionError = io.ConversionError()
#f = testInstance.convert(r"S:\Python\", 1", conversionError)
f = testInstance.convert(r"/Users/Hugo/20160401", "201604010000", 
conversionError)
end = time.time()
print("time elapsed " + str(end - start))

if(conversionError.conversionSucces):
    print("Conversion succesful")
if(conversionError.conversionSucces == False):
    print("Conversion failed: " + conversionError.conversionErrorLog)
print "Done!"

# Create a new subplot for two canals 1 & 3
a = np.amin(f.f)
filename = 'C:/Users/Hugo/20160401/201604010000.dat'
d = open(filename,'rb')
t = u"\u00b0"
headersize = 64
header = d.read(headersize)
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.set_title(header[:16] + ', ' +                          # station name
     'Canals: '+header[32:33]+' and '+header[34:35]+ ', '   # canals
     +'Temp'+header[38:43]+t+'C'                            # temperature
    +', '+'Time:'+header[26:32]+', '+'Date'+' '+header[16:26])      # date

plt.ylabel('Pico Tesle [pT]')
plt.xlabel('Time [ms]')
plt.plot(f.f[0,], label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(f.f[1,], label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False)
plt.grid()
# Create a new subplot for FFT
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title('Fast Fourier Transform')
plt.ylabel('Power [a.u.]')
plt.xlabel('Frequency Hz')
FFTdata = np.sqrt(f.f[0,]*f.f[0,]+f.f[1,]*f.f[1,])**1
samples = FFTdata.size
duration = 300 # in seconds
Fs = float(samples)/duration # sampling frequency (sample/sec)
delta_t = 1.0/Fs
t = np.arange(0, samples, 1)*delta_t
FFTdata_freq = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(FFTdata))**2
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(samples, d=delta_t)

# Printing data
plt.semilogy(freq, FFTdata_freq)
plt.grid()
#plt.savefig('S:/Hugo/'+"201604010000"+'.png', bbox_inches = 
'tight')
plt.show()
```

Contents of `f.f`:

```
>>> print f.f[0,]
[ -59.57011259 -74.20675537 -90.53224156 ..., -1676.9703173 -1676.9703173 -1676.9703173 ]

>>> print f.f[1,] 
[ 1.48413511e+00 4.96417605e+00 8.39303992e+00 ..., -1.67697032e+03 -1.67697032e+03 -1.67697032e+03]
```

iodata code:

```
import struct
import numpy as np

class ConversionError:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conversionSucces = True
        self.conversionErrorLog = "Correct"

    def reportFailure(self, errorlog):
        self.conversionSucces = False
        self.conversionErrorLog = errorlog

class DataStruct:
    def __init__(self,f,initTime,headerString):
        self.f = f
        self.initTime = initTime
        self.headerString = headerString

class InputConverter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.midAdc = 65536/2
        self.convFactor = 19.54

    def convert(self,filePath,fileName,conversionLog):
        try:
            d_file = open(filePath + "/" + fileName + ".dat", mode='rb')
         except IOError as e:
            conversionLog.reportFailure(e.strerror)

        file = d_file.read()
        datalen = len(file)
        headerString = file[:43]
        initime, = struct.unpack('>H', file[48:50])
        expectedMatrixWidth = (datalen - 72)/4
        outputMatrix = np.zeros((2, expectedMatrixWidth))
        index = 0;
        print "Processing..."
        for i in range(64, datalen-8, 4):
            e1, e2 = struct.unpack('>HH',file[i:i+4])
            outputMatrix[0, index] = (e1 - self.midAdc)/self.convFactor
            outputMatrix[1, index] = (e2 - self.midAdc)/self.convFactor
            index += 1


        return DataStruct(outputMatrix,initime,headerString)
```

Comment: ❶ Please don't rename a 3rd party library as one of the modules in the standard lib, I spent  some time to understand why I couldn't find `io.InputConverter` anywhere in the whole internet ❷ given that the `iodata` module has no documentation (except perhaps doc strings) it is very difficult to help unless you explain in the detail what object is `f` — the answer you've received seems reasonable, if the answer is not good for you it's because `f` is not a `ndarray` (or you haven't exactly understood the answer, who knows...) — Please [edit] your question to explain your use of `iodata` stuff.

Comment: I add everything, sorry about that.

Comment: No need to be sorry if you show commitment to improve, and your edit is clearly a step in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using array slicing:

```
plt.plot(f.f[0,][1:], label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(f.f[1,][:-1], label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
```

Edit:

Because of the nature of the data, slicing off more than just the first/last data points is appropriate, as @Dascienz suggests in the comments. Something like this, where the first and last 50 data points are sliced off from both series:

```
plt.plot(f.f[0,][50:-50], label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(f.f[1,][50:-50], label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
```

Comment: What happened? Plot same as before, or code threw and error? If so, what was the error?

Comment: Nothing has changed. None error occured, and the plot looks the same. I thought about defining that e.g "samples" are equals 266336, and then somehow link and then substract first and last record, but don't know if this work or how to do thi.

Comment: What's the output of `print f.f[0,]`?

Comment: Canal 1 - red line

Comment: I mean if you add the line `print f.f[0,]` to your code, what's the corresponding output in the console? I would expect it to be something like `array([val1, val2, val3, ...])`. I'm interested in what the first few `val`s are...

Comment: [  -59.57011259   -74.20675537   -90.53224156 ..., -1676.9703173
 -1676.9703173  -1676.9703173 ]

Comment: and if I print f.f[1,] there is:
[  1.48413511e+00   4.96417605e+00   8.39303992e+00 ...,  -1.67697032e+03
  -1.67697032e+03  -1.67697032e+03]

Comment: That's useful information! You should add it to the question :)

Comment: @Hiddenguy Does f.f[0,][1:] slice out the first value? If it does and the plot still has that red line, then the red line could be due to more than just your first data point. Try slicing out more points to see if the plot changes, e.g. f.f[0,][100:]... Also pico Tesle should read pico Tesla?

Comment: Great ! It worked, I did:
plt.plot(f.f[0,][53:][:-14], label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(f.f[1,][:-14], label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.75, linestyle="-")
and it fits perfectly. One question though, does this option delete this data, or just hide? I need this to be deleted, because I make FFT of this, and this frequency noise is not desired.

Comment: @Hiddenguy Thanks for marking my answer as correct! I would however suggest you mark this one as the correct one (see my latest edit).

Comment: If you want to then use the sliced data for the FFT, just store the slices in new variables, i.e. `f0 = f.f[0,][50:-50]` and `f1 = f.f[1,][50:-50]`. Then the FFT line becomes `FFTdata = np.sqrt(f0*f0 + f1*f1)**1`.

Comment: @landogardner I thought about it and I did it, but an error occured.

The part of code:

    fft1 = (f.f[0,][53:][:-14])
    fft2 = (f.f[1,][:-14])
    FFTdata = np.sqrt(fft1*fft1+fft2*fft2)**1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/iotest.py", line 47, in <module>
    FFTdata = np.sqrt(fft1*fft1+fft2*fft2)**1
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (266283,) (266336,)

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `53` in `fft2 = (f.f[1,][53:-14])`. So `fft1` and `fft2` weren't the same length, hence the error.

Comment: Ok, I did it early in the morning, and we are correct. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Long-winded explanation of why my first answer didn't seem to have an effect...

---

Removing the first data point from canal 1 and the last data point from canal 3 will not get rid of the anomalies. *Many* of the data points contribute to them.

Look at the last *three* data points of `f.f[0,]` (canal 1, in red) and `f.f[1,]` (canal 3, in blue): they are all the same value: `-1676.97003...`. This explains the purple (i.e. both red and blue) spike on the right of the graph.

Also, look at the first three values of `f.f[0,]` (canal 1, in red): they are roughly `-60`, `-75` and `-90`. Clearly getting rid of the very first one won't remove the anomalies on the left of the graph where the value goes all the way up to over `500`, and down to less than `-500`. These values must occur at indices above `2`, but still a lot less than `50000`, which is why it *looks* like they occur at `0`.

In short, to remove the anomalies you need clean up the data more carefully before plotting it, rather than just slicing off the first and/or last values (which is what my original answer did, and did correctly I believe).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your answer helped me with some things, but at the same time it made me a bit confused about one part of my code, which I will add to my question. Maybe you will be able to help me. I mean how to aply those changes to the fft plot (it is not finished btw. but I think it should change after slicing unnecessary data.